# PHP Capturing Date in wrong format

Tags: php, date

I know there is probably a simple answer to this but I have tried several things and nothing seems to work.

I have the following data taken from a JSON array:

```
{
"Id": 21973679,
"InvoiceNumber": 13,
"IssueDate": "14/08/2017",
"EulerID": 6162023,
"CustomerName": "Alderley plc",
"TotalAmount": "1,704.00",
"TotalTaxAmount": 0,
"Currency": "USD",
"DueDate": "13/09/2017",
"AmountDue": "0",
"Status": "Paid"
},
{
"Id": 21974783,
"InvoiceNumber": 23,
"IssueDate": "09/01/2017",
"EulerID": 6162023,
"CustomerName": "Alderley plc",
"TotalAmount": "11,000.00",
"TotalTaxAmount": 0,
"Currency": "GBP",
"DueDate": "08/02/2017",
"AmountDue": "0",
"Status": "Paid"
},
```

I am trying to get the IssueDate and DueDate. Both are stored in the format dd/mm/yyyy. However whatever I do php seems to not be able to capture them consistently.

```
$report_starting_date=$item1['IssueDate'];

$report_starting_date=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($report_starting_date));
```

For the 2nd Item invoice (23) it works fine if I echo the month it will return 1 this seems to work as the date could be either dd/mm or mm/dd however in the 1st item invoice (13) 14 cannot be a month and so php seems to set the date as 01/01/1970. I have no idea why I can store one item correct and not the other?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked you are parsing correct values  for date function ? 
echo  $item1['IssueDate']; and $item2['IssueDate'] and check whether.  strings are correct . this error comes when the strings has an issue.

Comment: Dates with a `/` are treated as US format (`mm/dd/YYYY`) and 14 isn't a valid month

Comment: Hi Mark yes I thought I might be something like this but the dates have to come with a / and I need them in UK format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) on supported formats, dd/mm/YYYY is not supported for `strtotime`.

You could use the `createFromFormat` function, and the documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $item1['IssueDate']);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $item1['IssueDate']);
```

Same:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $item1['IssueDate']);
```

[CreateFromFormat doc](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

In `$date` you have instance of `DateTime` class so you can print value using `format()` method like this `$date->format('d/m/Y');`

[Format method doc](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: When I do this I get - Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: in `$date` you get instance of DateTime class, so you can use `format()` method to print it `$date->format('d/m/Y');`

Answer (score 0):

The format 'dd/mm/yyyy' isn't supported with `strtotime`. Replacing the slashes with a dashes does fix your problem.

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $item1['IssueDate']);
$report_starting_date = date('d/m/Y', $time);
```

Note that this is more like a workaround which is not quite failsave. @kchason's answer might be the better choice here.

Comment: I have tried this but it still stores the date as mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below code to convert date string  to date. You need to supply 
the format of the date as first argument and date string as second argument.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $item1['IssueDate'])->format('d/m/Y');
```

Function `format()` returns date as string in supplied format.

Comment: I used this I told it to echo full date and then month for invoice (23) I got  - 09/01/2017 - 09 - however for invoice (13) I get 14/08/2017 - 01 - which is now ever more strange and month 01 is nowhere in the date